# My player died and if i clicked play in the main it will go to the last scene and say gameover

Tags: unityscript

I am trying to make a gameover scene where in if the player is game over The game will go back to the main or start up then when I press play it will start new game however if i am game over and go back to main and pressed play it will only show me Game over and wont continue my code is.....
Gameover code..

```
#pragma strict
import UnityEngine.UI;
private var StopGame: boolean=false;
private var showGUI: boolean=false;
var GUIstop: GameObject;
var StopMenu;
var respawn : Transform;



private var canvas : Canvas;

function Start()
{
canvas = GetComponent.<Canvas>();
canvas.enabled = false;
}



function Update () {

if(HealthControl.LOVES==0){
Pause();

  Application.LoadLevel (0);          

}

}
public function Pause()
{
canvas.enabled = !canvas.enabled;
Time.timeScale = Time.timeScale == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

public function Quit()
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR 
EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
#else 
Application.Quit();
#endif
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to call your scene in script, for instance: instead of 0 put the scene name.

Comment: not working still but thanks how to reset a scene ? :) thanks

Comment: okay whats the number 0 scene, is it menu or ingame

Comment: none but i replaced it to Application.LoadLevel("main")

Answer (score -1):

ok, so what does the StopGame do, beacuse if it have any function you have set it to false.

Comment: i dont have stop yet my game is if ever it bump a triangle it will decrease life and if it 0 game over will display and go back to main where if i press play i can see the character but it stopped moving

Comment: i think its the health script, since when the health is over maybe its 0 health forever so maybe try  when the scene is loading then you must add in the script that says health is full again

Comment: @minateo i did what you suggested it does help when i after my charcter died and go back to main and i clicked play i doesnt display game over unlike earlier thanks however the character is not moving >_< but thank you for helping

Comment: Please remember, this is a Question and Answer site, not a forum. The comments should be used for discussion about the post, and answers should be just that, answers to the question at hand. Unfortunately, you can't comment on others questions yet. Try and get enough rep to comment everywhere :)